# bootstrap3 nav-tabs not switching tabs

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap-3

This is currently the code I'm working with.

I want it to be able to switch tabs however it does not. I've tried taking off the active class however it still doesn't work.

I followed a tutorial to do it this way which didn't require JavaScript.

Can anyone help me find out why it is not working?

```
<div class="nav">
<ul class="nav nav-tabs">
 <li class="active"><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Home">Home</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Tournaments">Tournaments</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#About">About</a></li>
 <li><a data-toggle="tab" href="#Contact">Contact</a></li>
</ul>
</div>

<div class="tab-content">
<div id="Home" class="tab-pane fade">
<h3> example </h3>
</div>

    <div id="Tournaments" class="tab-pane fade">
    <h3>create images to show for new pages</h3>
    </div>

        <div id="About" class="tab-pane fade">
        <h3>6214</h3>
        </div>

            <div id="Contact" class="tab-pane fade"> 
            <h3>exds</h3>   
            </div>      

</div>
```

Comment: Are you loading jquery and bootstrap Js?

Comment: works fine here https://jsfiddle.net/DTcHh/8479/

Answer (score 0):

You are missing all javascripts.

```
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.11.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="//maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.2.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
```

Refer to this : https://codepen.io/jrcanicula/pen/vmojRG